# Google login button only works locally

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I have a Google login button in my app and it works locally, but when I deploy the code to a server it errors out.

Here's the code:

```
<!-- Google Sign In Button -->
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: "id_here",
        callback: handleCredentialResponse
    });
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById("googleButtonDiv"),
        { theme: "outline", size: "large", width: 400 }  // customization attributes
    );
    google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
}
```

On my local machine, it renders the "Sign In With Google" button correctly.

On any remote server, it throws this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at window.onload (<anonymous>:18:5)
    at t.<computed> (rocket-loader.min.js:1:9873)
    at l (rocket-loader.min.js:1:1105)
    at t.simulateStateAfterDeferScriptsActivation (rocket-loader.min.js:1:8728)
    at Object.callback (rocket-loader.min.js:1:3075)
    at t.run (rocket-loader.min.js:1:11340)
    at P (rocket-loader.min.js:1:3128)
    at Object.callback (rocket-loader.min.js:1:2851)
    at t.run (rocket-loader.min.js:1:11340)
    at rocket-loader.min.js:1:11156
```

It would appear that, for some reason, it doesn't load the Google library and therefore doesn't know what the `google` object is when I reference it.

But why? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove defer and async inside script tag and it will working.
[read here](https://codedamn.com/news/javascript/async-and-defer-in-script-tag)

Comment: Makes sense, but why does it work locally? Also, Google itself recommends defer/async loading.

Comment: When use async and defer, i think window.onload not wait script loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with the Google login button on server might be related to the authorized domains for the OAuth client ID. Here are some steps to follow:

**Authorized Domains for OAuth Client ID:**

**Authorized Domains on Google Cloud Console:**

- Visit the Google Cloud Console.
- Open the "APIs & Services" > "Credentials" page.
- Find the OAuth client ID used for Google Sign-In.
- Add the Firebase Hosting domain (.firebaseapp.com) and your - local development domain (localhost:3000 or whatever your local server uses) - to the list of authorized JavaScript origins.